# Is it possible to change class indices of Keras flow from directory

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I am using my own image data generator. It generates 0 ,90, 180 and 270 degrees rotated versions of image batches and returns them with their classes. I use built in `ImageDataGenerator` function to test the model. However `flow_from_directory` generates different class indices. Output of `train_generator.class_indices` is `{'0': 0, '90': 1, '180': 2, '270': 3}`. But `test_generator.class_indices` returns `{'0': 0, '180': 1, '270': 2, '90': 3}`. Simply I can change order of rotation angles but this problem is caused by the file system of operating system and I will run the code on a different operating system. In this case I need an automated solution. Is there a way to change the class indices of `flow_from_directory` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

looks like you can do

```
flow_from_directory(directory, 
                    classes={'0': 0, 
                             '90': 1, 
                             '180': 2, 
                             '270': 3}
                   )
```

Comment: Yes. But this does not change the class labels. I actually want to change the class labels.

Comment: Whatever you put there will be the class labels.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely you should be able to, and you can.

From Keras official document: https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/:
There's an argument name **classes** for both *flow_from_directory* and *flow_from_dataframe* method.

For *flow_from_directory* it explained:

**classes**: Optional list of class subdirectories (e.g. ['dogs', 'cats']). Default: None. If not provided, the list of classes will be automatically inferred from the subdirectory names/structure under directory, where each subdirectory will be treated as a different class (and the order of the classes, which will map to the label indices, will be alphanumeric). The dictionary containing the mapping from class names to class indices can be obtained via the attribute class_indices.

This means, when indicated in your *flow_from_directory* method classes=['dogs', 'cats'], label "dogs" then "cats" will be mapped into label indices by list order, i.e., 0, 1...

By not doing so, they will be in alphanumeric order, "dogs" is 1 then "cats" is 0.